# Values of the variables change according to vector values

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, glut

I send array `int Vetor[33];` by parameter for the function  `MontaVetorVerticalOtimizado(x, y, Vetor)`, inside this the array is filled, the problem is that after filling the array all the variables of the function  `OtimizaVerticalDentina()` are signed with the value of the array, it seems confusing, so I added images while debugging to make it more understandable:

**First function**:

```
void OtimizaVerticalDentina() {
    int Vetor[33];
    int x, y;
    for (x = 1; x < NewImage.SizeX() - 1; x++)
    {
        for (y = 10; y < NewImage.SizeY() - 10; y++)
        {
            MontaVetorVerticalOtimizado(x, y, Vetor);
            VerificaIntensidadeVetorVerticalOtimizado(Vetor);
            if (bPreenche) {
                NewImage.DrawPixel(x, y, 255, 255, 255);
            } else {
                NewImage.DrawPixel(x, y, 0, 0, 0);
                bPreenche = true;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Second function**:

```
void MontaVetorVerticalOtimizado(int Px, int Py, int Vetor[33])
{
    int x, y;
    int i = 0;
    unsigned char r, g, b;
    for(x = Px - 1; x <= Px + 1; x++)
    {
        for(y = Py - 10; y <= Py + 10; y++)
        {
           NewImage.ReadPixel(x, y, r, g, b);
           Vetor[i] = r;
           i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Note:

```
ImageClass NewImage; // global
```

**Before** filling the array variables are with their normal value
[image]

**After** populating the array the variables are with another value (the value that was added in the vector)[image]

*I have created other variables in the first method to test and they have also changed, does anyone have any idea what might be happening?

Comment: Which compiler? Have you added print statements to confirm (in case the debugger is lying to you)?

Comment: ah, my eye, too many white !

Comment: @Borgleader GNU GCC Compiler, I printed the value of the variable on the console before and after filling the array and showed that the compiler is not lying.

Comment: @Stargateur Sorry but this was necessary...

Comment: From the `<=` in your for loop I have the sneaking suspicion this is an array overrun, can you confirm you never index outside of your array size? (`< n - 10`, and then `<= n + 10`, seems like off by one). P.S: you can also try moving the x, y variables before the array declaration and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @Stargateur I'm manipulating images and applying filters on them, in my application I have two images (`ImageClass Image` and `ImageClass NewImage`)

Comment: @Borgleader I confirm you that it is not a problem in the for, testing without the method that fills the array, the index wont go outside of array size.

Comment: @Stargateur Yes.

Comment: Well, I agree with @Borgleader, try to print `if (i < 0 || i > 32) cout << "Problem: " << i << std::endl;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only explanation I can find is that you have a buffer overrun. That is is you are writing to this array (`Vetor`) which is not big enough and happen to overwrite unrelated memory in the process. In this case specifically you are overwriting the value of the variables `x` and `y` of the calling function.

I have demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9145e88e002edbdd):

```
#include <iostream>

void bar(int* arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 35; i++) arr[i] = 255;
}

void foo()
{
    int arr[33];
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        std::cout << x << '\n';
        bar(arr);
        std::cout << x << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

This produces: 0 255 and immediately terminates because the loop variable got overwritten and the subsequent `x < 5` check fails. You either have to increase the size of the array (if it turns out it was too small) or make sure you index within its bounds.